# Isolating audio tracks through mixing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have four audio recordings of a song, each with an instrument missing:

- the first contains everything except the bass track
- the second contains everything except the drum track
- the third contains everything except the guitar track
- the fourth contains everything except the vocal track

My goal is to isolate each of those tracks through mixing.

For example, if I mix the first recording with the inverse of the second recording, I end up with another recording that contains the drum track and the inverse of the bass track. To simplify the problem, I resorted to using letters to represent the four tracks: `B` = bass, `D` = drums, `G` = guitar, and `V` = vocals.

The first recording contains everything but the bass track and would be written `D G V`. The inverse of the second recording would be written `-B -G -V`. Mixing two tracks is equivalent to adding their samples together and therefore would produce `D -B` since the guitar and drum tracks will cancel each other out.

Mixing all possible combinations of the four recordings produces six additional recordings:

- `D -B`
- `G -B`
- `V -B`
- `G -D`
- `V -D`
- `V -G`

I still cannot come up with a combination of mixes that will completely isolate any of the tracks. What am I missing? Is there a technique I can use for solving these types of problems in the future?

Comment: This is an awesome question; do "inverses" of recordings really exist? I assume here, $B + B = B$, that sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to b equivalent to the following system of simultaneous equations, with unknowns $v,x,y,z$ representing the four tracks, and $a,b,c,d$ representing the recordings:

$$\begin{cases}
&&\;\;x&+y&+z&=a\\
&v&&+y&+z&=b\\
&v&+x&&+z&=c\\
&v&+x&+y&&=d
\end{cases}$$
[Solving](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2By%2Bz%3Da,+v%2By%2Bz%3Db,+v%2Bx%2Bz%3Dc,+v%2Bx%2By%3Dd) gives
$$v=\frac {-2a+b+c+d}3=s-a\\
x=\frac {\;a-2b+c+d}3=s-b\\
y=\frac {\;a+b-2c+d}3=s-c\\
z=\frac {\;a+b+c-2d}3=s-d$$
where $s=\frac 13(a+b+c+d)$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I mixed all of the recordings and then multiplied each of the samples by $\frac 13$. Then I mixed the result with the inverse of one of the recordings and was able to isolate a track.

Comment: Great! Glad to know it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you add all four together you get the sum of three times each track, so one third of it is BDGV.  If you subtract the first you have B left. So $B=\frac 13(BGV+BDV+BDG)-\frac 23DGV$ and similarly for all the others.

Answer (score 0):

If we have:

$$
-DGV\\
B-GV\\
BD-V\\
BDG-
$$

we have two ways to add them all, we either get $BDGV$ or $3BDGV$. If the second, divide by $3$, but either way then subtract any mix from the 'master mix'.