# Invert single vector dimension using only addition and inversion

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to perform an audio task, to try and isolate audio from mixed tracks. Specifically, I have two tracks with the same music but different sounds. Both are stereo. The only operations I can apply to them are inverting and mixing them. Doing so gets rid of the common parts and leaves on the difference.

> There is a similar question:
>   [Isolating audio tracks through mixing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305097/isolating-audio-tracks-through-mixing)
>   that solves a similar-looking problem through a system of linear
>   equations, however the conditions are different and I tried applying
>   the answer given as well as the solution the OP applied but I can't
>   get a meaningful answer out of it ([Wolfram
>   Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=i%2By%3Da,+i%2Bk%3Db,+j-k%3Dc&assumption=%22i%22+-%3E+%22Variable%22)).
>   I'm not sure if I've interpreted that solution correctly.

I've boiled the problem down to this:

- Track 1: `i + j`
- Track 2: `i + k`

`i` represents the common audio, `j` and `k` represent the audio unique to each track

I need to isolate either `i`, `j` or `k`. To do this, I believe it is sufficient to create an asymmetrically signed pair, or more explicitly one of these:

- `-i + j`
- `i - j`
- `-i + k`
- `i - k`

Since I can only invert a whole stereo track and mix tracks together, the only operations permitted are inverting the original vector pairs and adding them together (so it's allowed to have `-i -j` and `-i -k` but you can't directly go to `-i +j` etc.). Any new vectors created can also be inverted and added of course.

I'm thinking this is sort of a 3-dimensional geometric problem of adding and inverting vectors only, sort of an "only with a compass and straightedge" problem. In that representation, it would mean that under those constraints I have to produce a vector with exactly one dimension or one with exactly one negative and one positive dimension (such as `-i + j`). Either that or it's a system of linear equations like the other question but represented that way it seems there's no solution.

So far I've been unable to prove whether there is a solution (a series of steps to arrive from the original 2 to one of the needed 4) or find one by trial and error.

Is this possible given the constraints? Is there a way to prove whether this is possible at all?